# Cucumber Installation Issue in a typescript project

Tags: typescript, cucumber

I have a command line interface(written in typescript) which calls my framework(typescript based) with the feature files path.

Now, I am getting the following error when running my tests -

```
Error: 
          You're calling functions (e.g. "setDefaultTimeout") on an instance of Cucumber that isn't running.
          This means you have an invalid installation, mostly likely due to:
          - Cucumber being installed globally
          - A project structure where your support code is depending on a different instance of Cucumber
          Either way, you'll need to address this in order for Cucumber to work.
          See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/installation.md#invalid-installations
          
    at checkInstall
```

Output of `npm why @cucumber/cucumber` looks like this-

```
@cucumber/cucumber@8.10.0
node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber
  @cucumber/cucumber@"^8.2.1" from @frameworkPackage@0.5.16
  node_modules/@frameworkPackage
    @frameworkPackage@"*" from @cliMonoRepoTest@1.0.0
    packages/cliMonoRepoTest
      @cliMonoRepoTest@1.0.0
      node_modules/@cliMonoRepoTest
        @cliMonoRepoTest@"^1.0.0" from @cliMonoRepo.anotherMonoRepo1@1.0.0
        packages/anotherMonoRepo1
          @anotherMonoRepo1@1.0.0
          node_modules/@anotherMonoRepo1
            workspace packages/anotherMonoRepo from the root project
        @cliMonoRepoTest@"^1.0.0" from @anotherMonoRepo2@1.0.0
        packages/anotherMonoRepo2
          @anotherMonoRepo2@1.0.0
          node_modules/@anotherMonoRepo2
            workspace packages/anotherMonoRepo2 from the root project
        workspace packages/cliMonoRepoTest from the root project
```

I tried hardcoding the version of cucumber in my test package to 8.10.0 and then making sure it is this all through out the output of `npm why @cucumber/cucumber`, but couldn't get it working even after that.

The way we start cucumber tests is following -
`const cucumberPath = require.resolve(".bin/cucumber-js")` //I have tried updating this path to ude node modules too! however couldn't get it working even then.

Any suggestions on how I can debug this further?

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade to `@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.1.2`

The latest version could cause that.

By the way: That Node version are you using?